# Python requests not utilizing network

Tags: python, python-requests, network-programming

I'm trying to download a medium-sized APK file ( 10-300 MB ) and save it locally. My connection speed should be about 90 mbps, yet the process rarely surpasses 1 mbps, and my network doesn't seem to be anywhere near cap.

[image: Network]

I've verified the part that's getting stuck is indeed the SSL download with cProfile, and I've tried various advice on StackOverflow like reducing or increasing chunk size, to no avail. I'd love a way to either test if this could be a server-side issue, or advice on what am I doing wrong on the clientside.

Relevant code:

```
session = requests.Session() # I've heard session is better due to the persistent HTTP connection
session.trust_env = False
r = session.get(<url>, headers=REQUEST_HEADERS, stream=True, timeout=TIMEOUT) # timeout=60.
r.raise_for_status()
filename = 'myFileName'
i = 0
with open(filename, 'wb') as result:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
        if chunk:
            i += 1
            if(i % 5 == 0):
                print(f'At chunk {i} with timeout {TIMEOUT}')
            result.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to download many different files; Upon printing the urls I'm trying to download and testing in chrome I saw some of the URLs were significantly slower than other ones to download.

It seems like a server issue, which I ended up solving by picking a good timeout to the requests.